# how to find which scripts is running in windows 10 on startup?

Tags: brute-force, startupscript

in my pc with windows 10 OS, a scripts or (any thing I do not know) is running on startup, and try to login my email accounts. (maybe brute force attack)
I scan my pc with antivirus, and check my startup program in windows 10, and also clear history and cache in my chrome, but problem is staying.
so what should I do to find this scripts?